# What control is used to implement the screenshot preview in the marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

What control is used to implement the application screenshot preview in the windows phone marketplace. The control allows zooming , panning and scrolling of images.

This control is also used when scrolling through pictures in the "Pictures" application.

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.

Comment: There is no 'Plug-and-Play' control to achieve this in the default SDK & Silverlight Toolkit - it might be in the for-pay Telerik toolkit, but without that, you'll just need to think of what gestures you want to support.

Comment: @willmel I played with the demo they have on the marketplace. Some controls are nice , but they are little slower in response times compared to the controls in the WP SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post. In it Morten talks about how to achieve what you are looking for. I've used this in one of my own apps and it works great

http://sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control.aspx

Comment: That solves part of the problem. But i still would have to implement a listbox that snaps to an item. Anyways , thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "snaps" to an item?

Comment: Hmm this is hard to explain.But let me try .I was thinking of implementing this control as an itemtemplate in a listbox. Then when you flick , the list should stop at index n or n+1 , not in between n and n+1 (like the regular listbox behaviour).